# Setting Profilling in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi I am trying to time my queries in mysql by using the "set profiling=1;"

It works but for some reason its giving me this warning error.

0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1287 '@@profiling' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

Anyone have any idea what this means? I have googled the warning but no real answer

Answer (score 1):

Use [performance schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema.html) instead, it's the preferred way and profiling is deprecated since 5.6.7